# Matching and Replacing values of a column in a dataframe by date in r

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe, dplyr

Cheers,
I have two data frames with the following structure.

```
DF1:
Airlines           HeadQ      Date           Cost_Index
American           PHX        07-31-2016     220
American           ATL        08-31-2016     150
American           ATL        10-31-2016     150
Delta              ATL        10-31-2016     180
American           ATL        08-31-2017     200
```

Second data frame DF2 has the following structure:

```
DF2:
Airlines           HeadQ      Date          
American           ATL        09-30-2016
Delta              ATL        03-31-2017
```

Now looking up with data frames DF1 and DF2, I would like to alter DF1 to the following data frame.

```
DF1:
Airlines           HeadQ      Date           Cost_Index
American           PHX        07-31-2016     220
American           ATL        08-31-2016     0
American           ATL        10-31-2016     150
Delta              ATL        10-31-2016     180
American           ATL        08-31-2017     200
```

The condition is, lookup for Airlines and HeadQ of DF1 from DF2 and if DF1$Date < DF2$Date then make Cost_Index as 0 or else continue with Cost_Index.

I tried, unsuccessfully, with:

```
DF1$Cost_Index <- ifelse(DF1$Airlines == DF2$Airlines & DF1$HeadQ == DF2$HeadQ 
        & DF1$Date < DF2$Date, 0, DF1$Cost_Index)


Warning:
1: In DF1$Airlines == DF2$Airlines : longer object
length is not a multiple of shorter object length". 
2: In<=.default(DF1$Date, DF2$Date) : longer object length is not a
multiple of shorter object length

DF1:
Airlines           HeadQ      Date           Cost_Index
American           PHX        07-31-2016     220
American           ATL        08-31-2016     0
American           ATL        10-31-2016     0
Delta              ATL        10-31-2016     0
American           ATL        08-31-2017     200
```

Can anyone point me to right direction?

Note:

```
str(DF1$Date): Date, format: "2016-10-31"
str(DF2$Date): Date, format: "2016-08-31"
```

Comment: Not sure I love it, but `DF1 %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Cost_Index = ifelse(isTRUE(Date < DF2[DF2$Airlines == Airlines & DF2$HeadQ == HeadQ, 'Date']), 0L, Cost_Index))`

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of your previous Q.. You did the right thing by removing the check mark to that answer to indicate that you're looking for another approach, but asking it again isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a left join of `DF1` and `DF2` on the `Airlines` and `HeadQ` columns, and then change the value of `Cost_Index` based on if `Date.x`(Date from `DF1`) is smaller than `Date.y`(Date from DF2). With `dplyr` syntax (an additional check of if `Date.y` is `NA` is applied here according to your logic that if there is no match in DF2, the `Cost_Index` should remain the same):

```
library(dplyr)

# convert the Date column to Date class for comparison
df1$Date <- as.Date(df1$Date, "%m-%d-%Y")
df2$Date <- as.Date(df2$Date, "%m-%d-%Y")

df1 %>% 
       left_join(df2, by = c("Airlines", "HeadQ")) %>% 
       mutate(Cost_Index = ifelse(Date.x < Date.y & !is.na(Date.y), 0, Cost_Index), 
              Date = Date.x) %>% 
       select(-Date.x, -Date.y)

#   Airlines HeadQ Cost_Index       Date
# 1 American   PHX        220 2016-07-31
# 2 American   ATL          0 2016-08-31
# 3 American   ATL        150 2016-10-31
# 4    Delta   ATL        180 2016-10-31
```

Comment: Didn't know that `dplyr` could join table by two columns, without creating a helper column. Good answer.